# unbuffered query with MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unbuffered-queries

Are MySQLi queries unbuffered? If not, is there a way to do an unbuffered query, as with the non-MySQLi `mysql_unbuffered_query()`?

Comment: Do you mean that the query is not buffered, or that the response set is unbuffered?  *Why* would unbuffered be advantageous?

Comment: The response set. Per the docs for `mysql_unbuffered_query`: "This saves a considerable amount of memory with SQL queries that produce large result sets, and you can start working on the result set immediately after the first row has been retrieved as you don't have to wait until the complete SQL query has been performed."

Comment: Ah!  Very good.  I guess I've never faced moving a lot of data through a MYSQL connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mysqli_real_query() followed by mysqli_use_result()

Comment: `mysqli_use_result` appears to be just what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

MindStalker is right but maybe the easiest way is the one shown in the PHP manual
 http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Passing the MYSQLI_USE_RESULT constant as the *resultmode* argument, you can set [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to work as [mysql_unbuffered_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php)

```
<?php
$mysqli  = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$uresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo $row['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
$uresult->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

it works for me

```
$uresult = $mysqli_new->query("INSERT INTO world (username, userid, points, price, br, admin) 
VALUES ('$word[username]',$word[userid], $points, 0, 0, '$word[adminname]')", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
$uresult = $mysqli_new->query("SELECT username FROM world WHERE userid='$word[userid]'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
if ($uresult) 
{
    while ($row = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       echo "uresult: ".$row['username'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$uresult->close();
```