# mysqli_query stops php execution when result contains ~100,000 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this code:

```
<?php
$dbport         = 1578;
$dbhost         = "localhost";
$dbname         = "dbname";
$dbuser         = "dbuser";
$dbpswd         = "dbpswd";
$MySQLLink = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpswd, $dbname, $dbport);
$query = "SELECT * FROM assets_advanced_records LIMIT 100000";
echo "running query ".$query."<br>";
$result = mysqli_query($MySQLLink, $query) or die("Query failed (".$query."): ".mysqli_error($MySQLLink));
echo "query succeeded<br>";
mysqli_close($MySQLLink);
?>
```

Execution stops at mysqli_query() immediately; the page is no longer loading.

Output looks like this:

```
running query SELECT * FROM assets_advanced_records LIMIT 100000
```

If I reduce LIMIT to 10000 I get the correct output:

```
running query SELECT * FROM assets_advanced_records LIMIT 10000
query succeeded
```

What could be causing this?

MySQL version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1

PHP version: 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3

I get this in the console when execution stops:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

UPDATE:

Checking /var/log/apache2/error.log I'm getting errors like:

```
[Fri Dec 30 15:13:23.983920 2016] [:error] [pid 1907] [client 10.10.6.116:54978] FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 806912 bytes) in /var/www/html/debug_tools2.php on line 491, referer: http://10.10.6.24/debug_tools2.php
```

Comment: are you trying to print all 100000 records in single page?

Comment: if so , you can use pagination for this

Comment: No, I'm just a bit worried that the query doesn't fail or timeout, but simply stops execution (which doesn't seem like normal behavior). The code above was written specifically to test this issue. I don't actually need to run that query, but I need to know why it isn't working in case it comes up in the future.

Comment: I think that we are talking about max_execution_time defined in php.ini http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Pretty sure it isn't max_execution_time; I get the error immediately, not after the 300 seconds my max_execution_time is set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log was the key:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

You ran out of memory. You had  128MB to work with, and your result set was bigger than that, so the script crapped out.

When you run `mysqli_query` it loads the entire result set into memory, so it makes sense that a large enough result set would be too large for the amount of memory php has been allocated. There are a few solutions:

• **Chunking**, just grab ~10000 records at a time

```
for ($offset=0;$offset<10;$offset++) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM assets_advanced_records LIMIT ".10000*$offset.", 10000";
//do stuff...
}
```

• **Increase php's memory limit**. If you have the permissions to do so: You are currently at 128M, jack it up with

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1G');
```

at the top of your script, or just throw caution to the wind and max out with

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1')
```

• **Use an unbuffered query**. That won't load the entire resultset into memory. You can read about [`mysqli_real_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php) with [`mysqli_use_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) to achieve that. Further reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.html, [unbuffered query with MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982016/unbuffered-query-with-mysqli), http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php

Comment: Yep, that did it. Looks like the query was taking about 268MB. I just edited /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini and increased memory_limit. Thanks for answering!